# Gnuplot Bar chart with error bars

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have the following data

```
Name   Value of the bar   Confidence interval
A      0.62               [0.59 0.63]
B      0.64               [0.54 0.72]
C      0.51               [0.46 0.67]
D      0.33               [0.25 0.36]
```

I tried to plot it as a bar chart with A,B,C and D labeling each bar and with and error bar.

By using

`plot "my.dat" using 1; with boxes` I only get a bar chart. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the records and in addition to Christoph's solution, for those users who do not have `sed` available. There is a simple ***gnuplot-only*** solution without external tools, hence, *platform-independent*.

Standard column separator is whitespace. So, in order to handle the unfortunate brackets in the input data, take `strcol(3)` (check `help stringcolumn`), neglect the first character (check `help substr`) and convert it into a real number (check `help real`). For the 4th column gnuplot will ignore the trailing `]` without further action.

**Data:** `SO24871941.dat`

```
Name   Value of the bar   Confidence interval
A      0.62               [0.59 0.63]
B      0.64               [0.54 0.72]
C      0.51               [0.46 0.67]
D      0.33               [0.25 0.36]
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### add errorbar to boxes from special data format
reset

FILE = "SO24871941.dat"

set style fill solid 0.3
set boxwidth 0.8
set yrange[0:*]
set key noautotitle

plot FILE u 0:2:0:xtic(1) w boxes lc var, \
       '' u 0:2:(real(strcol(3)[2:])):4 w yerr lc rgb "black" pt 7 lw 2
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 5.2.8)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you also want errorbars, you must add a second plot with the `yerrorbars` plotting style. The brackets aren't very handy in the data file, so I remove them with a `sed` command:

```
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.8
set yrange [0:*]
unset key
plot "< sed 's/[][]//g' my.dat" using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, \
     '' using 0:2:3:4 with yerrorbars lc rgb 'black' pt 1 lw 2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted.

Comment: Is there any possibility to change the color of the bars? So that each bar has a different color or pattern (filled with dots or lines)

Comment: Yes, you can use e.g. `lc variable` to color the bars based on some value (possible the row number): `plot "< sed 's/[][]//g' my.dat" using 0:2:0:xtic(1) lc variable with boxes`.