# gnuplot: How can I add error bars that start at 0?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add error bars to my histogram chart that start at 0.

Examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023736/gnuplot-barchart-histogram-with-errorbars) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871941/gnuplot-bar-chart-with-error-bars) but both of them start at the peak of the bar chart.

This is how I'm currently producing the bar graphs:

```
set style histogram clustered

unset title
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set boxwidth 1
set style fill solid
set term png
set output "figure.png"

plot [-0.5:4.5][0:10] "data.dat"using 2:xtic(1) title "Title 1" with histograms fillstyle pattern 1, \
    "" using 3 title "Title 2" with histograms fillstyle pattern 2, \
    "" using 4 title "Title 3" with histograms fillstyle pattern 3
```

I can add a 4th column to my data.dat file which will have the height of the error bars but I don't know the correct way of plotting it.

EDIT:

```
set style fill solid 1.0
w = 0.15
set boxwidth 0.3
set key top right

set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set xrange[0.5:5.9]
set yrange[0:300]
set xtics 1

plot "data.dat" u ($1-w):2 w boxes lc rgb "read" ti "Title 1", \
     '' u ($1+w):3 w boxes lc rgb "green" ti "Title 2", \
     '' u ($1+w*3):4 w boxes lc rgb "blue" ti "Title 3", \
     '' u ($1-w):5 w impulses dt 3 lw 3 lc rgb "black" ti "Title 4", \
     '' u ($1-w):5 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u ($1+w):6 w impulses dt 3 lw 3 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u ($1+w):6 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u ($1+w*3):7 w impulses dt 3 lw 3 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u ($1+w*3):7 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u 0:(NaN):xtic(1) not
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not drawing it "manually" `with boxes` and `with impulses` and `with points`? You did not provide example data, so I created some data.
For example like this. Maybe be there are shorter ways.

**Edit:**  Using xtic strings instead of numbers.

**Code:**

```
### manual histogram and percentile line
reset session

# n MedianX MedianY  Perc90x  Perc90y
$Data <<EOD
  A     7.1     6.2     20.3     16.4
  B     8.1     7.2     22.3     17.4
  C     9.1     8.2     24.3     18.4
  D    10.1     9.2     26.3     19.4
  E    11.1    10.2     28.3     20.4
EOD

set style fill solid 1.0
w = 0.15
set boxwidth 0.3
set key top left
set xrange[-0.5:4.5]
set xtics 1

plot $Data u ($0-w):2 w boxes lc rgb "red" ti "Median x", \
     '' u ($0+w):3 w boxes lc rgb "blue" ti "Median y", \
     '' u ($0-w):4 w impulses dt 3 lc rgb "black" ti "90th Percentile", \
     '' u ($0-w):4 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u ($0+w):5 w impulses dt 3 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u ($0+w):5 w p pt 7 ps 1 lc rgb "black" not, \
     '' u 0:(NaN):xtic(1) not
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (for 3 columns and `with errorlines` instead of `impulses` and `points`)

**Code:**

```
### manual histogram and percentile line
reset session

# n MedianX MedianY MedianZ  Perc90x  Perc90y  Perc90z
$Data <<EOD                                  
  A     7.1     6.2     5.3     20.4     16.5     12.6
  B     8.1     7.2     6.3     22.4     17.5     13.6
  C     9.1     8.2     7.3     24.4     18.5     14.6
  D    10.1     9.2     8.3     26.4     19.5     15.6
  E    11.1    10.2     9.3     28.4     20.5     16.6
EOD

set style fill solid 1.0
w = 0.20
set boxwidth 0.20
set key top left
set xrange[-0.5:4.5]
set xtics 1

plot $Data u ($0-w):2 w boxes lc rgb "red" ti "Median x", \
     '' u ($0):3 w boxes lc rgb "blue" ti "Median y", \
     '' u ($0+w):4 w boxes lc rgb "web-green" ti "Median z", \
     '' u ($0-w):(0):(0):5 w errorlines ls 0 ti "90th Percentile", \
     '' u ($0):(0):(0):6 w errorlines ls 0 not, \
     '' u ($0+w):(0):(0):7 w errorlines ls 0 not, \
     '' u 0:(NaN):xtic(1) not, \
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please show me how to use letters instead of numbers for the xtics? I tired changing them in the data file but nothing plots.

Comment: Then you have to use `$0` as x-coordinate (see `help pseudocolumns`) and use another plot command to get the (unshifted) xtic labels. I modified the code. I hope this fully answers your question.

Comment: I tried to modify your code to work with 3 columns. I got the impulses and bars to work but I can't get the xtics to plot correctly. When I change the number to letters in the data.dat file it only plots B, C, D, E and none of the bars or impulses.

Comment: it's hard to tell, if I don't see your actual code.